# How can I convert an ndarray to a matrix in scipy?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, numpy

How can I convert an ndarray to a matrix in numpy?  I'm trying to import data from a csv and turn it into a matrix.

```
from numpy import array, matrix, recfromcsv
my_vars = ['docid','coderid','answer1','answer2']
toy_data = matrix( array( recfromcsv('toy_data.csv', names=True)[my_vars] ) )
print toy_data
print toy_data.shape
```

But I get this:

```
[[(1, 1, 3, 3) (1, 2, 4, 1) (1, 3, 7, 2) (2, 1, 3, 3) (2, 2, 4, 4)
  (2, 4, 3, 1) (3, 1, 3, 3) (3, 2, 4, 3) (3, 3, 3, 4) (4, 4, 5, 1)
  (4, 5, 6, 2) (4, 2, 4, 3) (5, 2, 5, 4) (5, 3, 3, 1) (5, 4, 7, 2)
  (6, 1, 3, 3) (6, 5, 4, 1) (6, 2, 5, 2)]]
(1, 18)
```

What do I have to do to get a 4 by 18 matrix out of this code?  There's got to be an easy answer to this question, but I just can't find it.

Comment: Why don't you re-shape it rather than use matrix?

Comment: Reshape won't let me convert a 1x18 object into a 4x18 object, will it?

Comment: How do you propose converting a 1x18 object into a 4x18 object? Where do the other rows come from?

Comment: See the output above: recfromcsv imports the 4x18 csv file as an 18-row ndarray, with each row containing a 4-tuple of data.  I want to convert that into a 4x18 matrix.

Comment: If you have an 18x4 ndarray then just use `.T` to transpose it to an 18x4 ndarray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the ultimate goal is to make a matrix, there's no need to create a recarray with named columns. You could use `np.loadtxt` to load the csv into an ndarray, then use `np.asmatrix` to convert it to a matrix:

```
import numpy as np
toy_data = np.asmatrix(np.loadtxt('toy_data.csv',delimiter=','skiprows=1))
print toy_data
print toy_data.shape
```

yields

```
[[ 1.  1.  3.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  4.  1.]
 [ 1.  3.  7.  2.]
 [ 2.  1.  3.  3.]
 [ 2.  2.  4.  4.]
 [ 2.  4.  3.  1.]
 [ 3.  1.  3.  3.]
 [ 3.  2.  4.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  4.]
 [ 4.  4.  5.  1.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.  2.]
 [ 4.  2.  4.  3.]
 [ 5.  2.  5.  4.]
 [ 5.  3.  3.  1.]
 [ 5.  4.  7.  2.]
 [ 6.  1.  3.  3.]
 [ 6.  5.  4.  1.]
 [ 6.  2.  5.  2.]]
(18, 4)
```

Note: the skiprows argument is used to skip over the header in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

You can just read all your values into a vector, then reshape it.

```
fo = open("toy_data.csv")

def _ReadCSV(fileobj):
  for line in fileobj:
    for el in line.split(","):
      yield float(el)


header = map(str.strip, fo.readline().split(","))
a = numpy.fromiter(_ReadCSV(fo), numpy.float64)
a.shape = (-1, len(header))
```

But there may be an even more direct way with newer numpy.